# PHP Sessions only working in a certain directory

Tags: php, session, nginx, apc

I have a simple PHP login system, in the root HTML directory, there is a `login.php`, which then directs you to a `/m/` directory (For members area) once you have successfully logged in. The problem is, PHP session variables are working ONLY in the `/m/` directory, once I go outside it, sessions stop working, once I go back in, they work again.

I made sure it wasn't my code by running the whole thing on `000webhost`, and everything worked perfectly as it should.

My `session.save_path` is set to `/var/lib/php/session`, which does exist and is writable (To my knowledge because there are a bunch of session files in there). I am running `PHP 5.3.3`, `nginx 1.6.2`, and `PHP APC 3.1.9`.

I can provide more information in a specific area if needed.

Comment: What does your session cookie look like?

Comment: The cookie is always stored on the cilent side.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9LA3krQB